# Why does IoC has influence on Controller creation and how to fix that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have strange issue in my ASP .NET MVC application. I have some controller and some `IHelper` and it's implementation `Helper` for this controller. When I use this helper like below:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var hepler = new Helper();
    helper.DoStuff();
    ...
}
```

every thing is OK. But When I try to inject this helper as property for controller:

```
public IHelper Helper { private get; set; }
...    
public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {            
        Helper.DoStuff();
        ...
    }
```

and in my IoC configuration class I have:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
          {
              // Helpers
              x.For<IHelper>().Use<Helper>();              
              ...
              x.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IHelper>().Use<Helper>();
              ...
          }
```

The thing is I have a LOT of different helpers, managers, repositories and other stuff initialized using IoC pattern in IoC configuration class and successfully injected to each of my controllers. But whe I try to inject this `Helper` I get:

```
InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

I know that the issue is in IoC and in this `Helper` because I googled [this](http://www.ryanonrails.com/2012/05/30/mvc3-make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless-public-constructor/), removed `Helper` from IoC configuration class, used it like `var hepler = new Helper();` and everything worked fine. But I can't understand what is the problem in? Did any one saw such issue before? I even can't understan how **Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor** and **IoC initializing of one of controllers properties** can be related when everything works great for another helpers, etc.

**EDITS**
**P.S.** I am using StructureMap IoC framework and ASP .NET MVC 4.0.

Comment: It would probably help to mention that you're using StructureMap.

Comment: Not sure which IoC system you're using, but have you tried making the `set` `public` instead of `private`?

Comment: I just noticed that too... and it's the `get` that's private, not the `set`.  Would that even work?  Since the property isn't even being used, it's unclear what its intent it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, set IS public. Get is private to make this property accessible for read only in the current controller. Set has the same access lvl as the property itself - public, to make it accessible for testing (mocking) and IoC framework.

Comment: A property whose setter has greater visibility than its getter smells like an anti-pattern. Use constructor parameter injection instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you're not actually using dependency injection here:

```
public IHelper Helper { private get; set; }
...    
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var hepler = new Helper();
    helper.DoStuff();
    ...
}
```

You've created a property of type `IHelper`, and perhaps your IoC framework is even trying to populate that property with an implementation, but in your action method you're still just directly instantiating an instance of `Helper` without using the injected property, so you still have a hard dependency on `Helper` instead of `IHelper`.

More to the point, the error you're getting may very well depend on both the IoC framework you're using and the ASP.NET MVC version you're using.  The IoC *looks like* it might be StructureMap, is that the case?  For MVC, which version is it?

Different versions of ASP.NET MVC handle dependency resolution in their controller constructors differently.  In an MVC 4 application, for example, you can create an implementation of an `IDependencyResolver` and use that for the controllers.  Something like this:

```
public class DomainDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IoCContainer Container;

    public DomainDependencyResolver(IoCContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
            return Container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
        else
            return Container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return Container.GetAllInstances()
                        .Where(s => s.GetType() == serviceType);
    }
}
```

This uses a generic `IoCContainer` instance (similar to the Common Service Locator), but if you just want to use your IoC implementation directly that's probably fine.  The main thing is to implement `GetService` and `GetServices` so that your IoC container returns the implementations for any requested types.  You'd then set ASP.NET MVC to use this dependency resolver implementation for its controllers in the application startup (in `Global.asax.cs`):

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new DomainDependencyResolver(IoCContainerFactory.Current));
```

The only thing you'd have to change there is the reference to the IoC container.  I'm using my own generic version, which is of type `IoCContainer` and is in a static property called `Current` on an `IoCContainerFactory`.  You'd be using whichever framework you're using, so you'd just need to change the constructor of the dependency resolver implementation to match whatever you're going to pass it.

Comment: Exactly! ASP.NET MVC needs either a parameterless constructor to create Controllers or a `DependencyResolver` to call when resolving Controller instances. Another custom resolver, made for StructureMap, can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706776/how-to-configure-dependency-injection-with-asp-net-mvc-3-rtm